# length and capacity in Go slices

Tags: arrays, go, slice

Say we have slice of b such

```
b:= make([]int, 0, 5) // length: 0, cap: 5
```

and slice of "c" made from slice of "b"

```
c:= b[:2]  // length: 2 (?), cap: 5
```

The question if how come we have length of 2 for "c"? I was expecting length of zero as well, like b, since we are making c out of b

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yep, slicing can get you access to the elements beyond the `len` of the original slice (though not beyond its `cap`, or who knows what memory you'd be accessing).

This means, for example, that you can implement `append`-like functionality, returning a "grown" slice with `len` increased to something closer to the `cap`. That is, `append`'s access to the region between `len` and `cap` isn't only available to built-in functions; you have it as well. Look at [Append: an example](https://blog.golang.org/slices#TOC_9.) in the Go blog entry on slices to see it done (and if interested read the whole post; it helps make slices as a whole make sense).

[The spec on slice expressions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_expressions) (and [slice types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_types)) and the [Slice Tricks page](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/SliceTricks) may also be interesting.